# UNIX socket connection refused

Tags: c, macos, sockets, unix-socket

Under OS-X, I've got process named 'listener' that is waiting on 'accept' to read data from local unix socket named listener_socket. unfortunately, any attempt to connect that socket terminate in 'connection refused' error.

Using lsof, to make sure that the 'listener' actually listen to this socket :

```
sudo lsof -p 570
COMMAND PID USER   FD     TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
...
listener  570 root    3u    unix 0x48a2751a1bad61ef        0t0        /private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket
```

Notice that the file is, in fact, a valid unix socket :

```
file /private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket /private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket: socket
```

However, it still fail to connect, even when i'm using an alternative way from command like (using socat command)

```
sudo socat LOCAL:/private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket,interval=1 EXEC:'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',nofork

2015/11/23 00:57:33 socat[928] E connect(3, LEN=49 AF=1 "/private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket", 49): Connection refused
```

perhaps there are more i can do to figure out why i cannot send data to the socket, even-though it's obvious that 'listener' waiting for this data on the other side ?

here's the relevant part of my code :

sender:

```
sockfd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "%s", LISTENER_SOCKET_PATH);
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)
write ...
```

receiver:

```
fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
unlink(sock_name); // in case the socket is used before
listen(server->fd, 5); // we don't reach 5 listeners for sure ...
chmod(sock_name, mode); // giving root privilages
accept(server->fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server->address, &server->address_length);
read ...
```

thanks

Comment: Please post the source code, preferably a "minimum, complete, verifiable example". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the socket file?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, notice that 'ls -ltr' shows : srw-------  1 root  daemon  0 Nov 22 07:09 /private/var/run/my_sockets/listener_socket
and the parent process that runs listener has pid 0, so listener is also having root privilages
0    49     1   0  6:36AM ??         3:24.06 /Library/Application Support/PaloAltoNetworks/Traps/bin/trapsd

Comment: @keithmo, i've posted my code, while removing the error checks, and other irrelevant parts.

Comment: @Zohar this isn't enough - you need to post a _complete_, _compilable_ (but still _minimal_) example.

Comment: @keithmo, unfortunately, the sender / receiver code i've supplied is running on one out of many threads in both sender and receiver processes. while working on sterile environment, it did work. i wonder what reasons can lead to connection refuse message.

Comment: Two things: On the receiving side, you're missing a call to `bind()` (probably accidentally removed when you prepared the code for posting here), and 2) in `accept(server->fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server->address, &server->address_length);` are you setting server->address_length before calling `accept()`?

Comment: Try changing rights to the socket to see if it is such a problem or not. Verify that euid is the right one, etc. Without any usable code we can't test. There can also be a sandboxing problem under osx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server seems to miss calling `bind()` on the listening socket.